# Foreach updates every record in a LINQ result

Tags: c#, linq, wcf-data-services

I use a WCF Data Service to get data using pagination.

I have to provide a specific object (ExtraData) for the clients, but in the database, there is no such data. It is a combined data of a few tables and it has 1 row to make it cross-joinable.

As WCF Data Services does not allow dynamic object creation, the returned data must be inside the query.

The service return the updated data in the form what the clients require.

I have the following method:

```
[WebGet]
public IQueryable<ExtraData> GetExtraData(string groupID)
{
 var query= (from data in context.Data                           
            join information in context.Information on information.ID equals data.InformationID into tempInformation
            from information in tempInformation.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from extraData in context.ExtraData // cross-joining the dummy
            where data.GroupID == groupID
            select new
            {
             ExtraData = extraData,
             Data = data,
             InformationText = information.Text
            }).ToList();

//After the execution, I intend to modify the result (as it is a dummy record yet):

 query.ForEach(
      item =>
      {       
          item.ExtraData.DataID = item.Data.ID;
          item.ExtraData.Name = item.Data.NameAux; 
          item.ExtraData.Group = elem.Data.ExtraGroup;       
      }
      );

  return (from item in query
              select item.ExtraData).AsQueryable();
}
```

Unfortunately, it modifies *every record each time*, so I end up having the same record multiple times.

What should I modify to make the `ExtraData` records unique?

UPDATE:

Inside the foreach, I get this data:

```
3ca65876-c88f-4849-bef5-170e62f084ec Name16
b705ebc3-8245-4c16-8045-a79ef15192d2 Name16
b8bb423c-02ff-4e9a-b941-a20a9c69dd12 Name Second 16
4e3d3496-4b36-4dab-b471-a43ffb075345 Other16
f93a2358-818e-4929-a51a-46a7b7080bd4 Test16
a4bca994-73d2-4d0e-a18a-2539067a7498 Test Second 16
c7474a92-430a-46ad-bc3d-7e526dfb2647 New Test 16
6117f1b6-3f6b-4fae-b448-2778d68d0877 New Test Mod 16
8e831455-4305-4ee3-b56d-3b0e23131df8 Test Mod 16
```

In the result set, I get this:

```
<entry><id>http://localhost/MyService/Service.svc/ExtraData(guid'8e831455-4305-4ee3-b56d-3b0e23131df8')</id><category term="ExtraData" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" title="ExtraData" href="ExtraData(guid'8e831455-4305-4ee3-b56d-3b0e23131df8')" /><title /><updated>2015-11-10T10:07:36Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:ID m:type="Edm.Guid">8e831455-4305-4ee3-b56d-3b0e23131df8</d:ID><d:Name>Test Mod 16</d:Name><d:Group m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Group></m:properties></content></entry>
<entry><id>http://localhost/MyService/Service.svc/ExtraData(guid'8e831455-4305-4ee3-b56d-3b0e23131df8')</id><category term="ExtraData" scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /><link rel="edit" title="DSPaciens" href="ExtraData(guid'8e831455-4305-4ee3-b56d-3b0e23131df8')" /><title /><updated>2015-11-10T10:07:36Z</updated><author><name /></author><content type="application/xml"><m:properties><d:ID m:type="Edm.Guid">8e831455-4305-4ee3-b56d-3b0e23131df8</d:ID><d:Name>Test Mod 16</d:Name><d:Group m:type="Edm.Int32">1</d:Group></m:properties></content></entry>
```

Comment: Do you really need to cross-join that ExtraData? This *will* cause a lot of records. Would a `ExtraData = new ExtraData()` already be enough?

Comment: I can't use any instantiate as Data Services fail on creating new entites. It has to be inside the query. It contains one line, so cross-join should produce no extra records, only extra columns.

Comment: Well, you are creating a cross join (intentionally). Why don't you just remove that? Note also, that these are not all distinct ExtraData objects. There's just one such object per row in the database. You're writing the the same objects many times.

Comment: What do you want to achieve in general?

Comment: @usr See the update initial post.

Comment: @usr How could I make the ExtraData object to be a different object for every anonym object?

Comment: OK, I see. Why don't you manually create the objects in the ForEach? Why is that disallowed? It's not like you are returning a real query anyway. You are returning a "fake query" that is disconnected from the database.

Comment: @usr I can't create new object to replace the ExtraData object, it is a read-only property.

Comment: Create new objects then. Like `new { a = 1234, ... }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we were very close to the solution :)

The key element was what @usr wrote:

> There's just one such object per row in the database. You're writing
>   the the same objects many times.

Unfortunately, the selected anonymous object are *read-only*, so I had to create a wrapper-class that holds the necessary data:

```
public class CombinedData
{
   public ExtraData ExtraData { get; set; }
   public Data Data { get; set; }
   public string InformationText {get; set; }
}
```

Then use it inside the query:

```
var query= (from data in context.Data                           
            join information in context.Information on information.ID equals data.InformationID into tempInformation
            from information in tempInformation.DefaultIfEmpty()
            from extraData in context.ExtraData // cross-joining the dummy
            where data.GroupID == groupID
            select new CombinedData
            {
             ExtraData = extraData,
             Data = data,
             InformationText = information.Text
            }).ToList();
```

Then create a new ExtraData object inside the `ForEach` loop:

```
query.ForEach(
      item =>
      {   
          item.ExtraData=new ExtraData();    
          item.ExtraData.DataID = item.Data.ID;
          item.ExtraData.Name = item.Data.NameAux; 
          item.ExtraData.Group = elem.Data.ExtraGroup;       
      }
      );
```

Now, it works. Thanks for pointing me to the right direction :)

Comment: Yeah, this works as well. I'd rather advise a different pattern, though: `return query.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { ... }).AsQueryable();`. And fill in `...` appropriately. That results in much nicer code. Less side effects and mutation, no misuse of entity classes as DTOs.

Comment: Agreed, your approach is much nicer. However, in the given circumstances, my entity class acts as a DTO (by purpose, and it does not create or update existing database records), so I use the above code. Thanks for the great help.